# Is it possible to have a plugin triggered on any page load without having to re initialize it on every view loaded

Tags: javascript

I do not have any code to display as code would not help towards my question.  I am wondering if there is a advanced JavaScript technique that can allow my plugin be called and ran against all items needed but without having to initialize it on every view in mb. Now the layout shared method is not what I mean.  So fir example if I placed said plugin in a global scope in one he file and did a regular

$(document).ready(call plugin unit here)

Would that then be bound to every page and view so I do not need it to be added on every view or is thee some kind of event I can bind to when i initialize my plugin within the global.js file so it will be ran on any view or HTML page that the user goes to working on its elements?  Kind of how using the older method event binding ".live"  would handle all current items and future ones.

I am trying to find this out or find out if possible how to handle it.  My plugin I'm testing with is proprietary so cannot post code here but uses the regular concept of a each loop on on elements affected. Hopefully my question has been stated with a clear goal.

Now understanding that it needs to run against any new target items that may not have been loaded prior but may come down the pipe a few page navigations away I'm not sure I can do this.  Unless there is some kind of event in the global JavaScript scope I can bind to and during initialization of my plugin within the one section of code will then cause it to run against all items on what ever page is loaded. Please no rude downing with "we need to see code" as that would not affect an answer here and as mentioned the plugin cannot be publically displayed. Please helpful comments only and sorry if over complicating this and overlooking the answer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need to see code. It looks like you are not understanding the basics of the server/client model...

Comment: I could load it on the _Layout, but am wondering if there is something i am not aware of on how to handle a plugin in JQuery. I usually have to have it at every view level. I do and have worked in MVC for pretty long time now. Just asking if there was a method i am not aware of. I can post the plugin code, but it is just a wrapper for a custom tool tip that read is it's data form a SQL table. I am asking more theoretical question. Sorry if it was misstated. -Thanks-

Comment: I understand that every view has new items rendered, so you usually have to run javascript again the new view returned. What i am wondering is for example how the '.Live' binding worked for elements that did not yet exist on the DOM? Can you make a plugin work the same way against any elements that exist now and in future that it may need to work against?